# If internet connection speed high, load this video, else show this picture

Tags: javascript, php, html, html5-video, internet-connection

I want to automatically play a video on the homepage. In case of bad internet connection or slower internet speed you should show an image instead of the video.

example video

```
<video>
   <source src="https://quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

In case of bad internet connection or slower internet speed

```
<img src="thisimg.jpg" data-alt="thisimg">
```

is that possible?

Comment: I don't think so. You don't know the quality/speed of a connection to your server until you actually test it. Testing is possible of course, and then you could do it, but a test takes time, and I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: you can use hls library , video.js for solve this issue. https://videojs.com/

Comment: @AmirKaftari It would be helpful to give a direct link into the documentation of videojs where this issue is addressed.

Comment: this is documentation for video.js : https://docs.videojs.com/

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the **poster** attribute of video element. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-poster

> **Poster:** A URL for an image to be shown while the video is downloading. If this
>   attribute isn't specified, nothing is displayed until the first frame
>   is available, then the first frame is shown as the poster frame.

Comment: This would still try to download the video. The question is: "show an image **instead** of the video."